# We are getting angular digest cycle issue after updating angular.min.js v1.6.9

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst

We are migration angular.min.js v1.3.0 js to angular.min.js v1.6.9.So we are getting following error message Please suggestion any solution.Thanks

::Error Block::

> angular.min.js:122 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
>
> ```
>     at angular.min.js:6
>     at m.$digest (angular.min.js:145)
>     at m.$apply (angular.min.js:147)
>     at l (angular.min.js:101)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.N.onload (angular.min.js:106)
> ```

We tried different approach to resolve digest cycle issue

1. https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/docs/api/ng/provider/$rootScopeProvider
2. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$rootScopeProvider
3. https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/docs/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
4. https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/docs/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-3-to-1-4

Answer (score 0):

> Please suggestion any solution.

This error occurs when the application's model becomes unstable and each `$digest` cycle triggers a state change and subsequent `$digest` cycle. AngularJS detects this situation and prevents an infinite loop from causing the browser to become unresponsive.

One common mistake is binding to a function which generates a new array every time it is called. **The solution is** to return the same array object if the elements have not changed.<sup>[1](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/docs/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D)</sup>

You will get better error messages if you use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`.

Answer (score 0):

```
its working for me

var MobileApp = angular.module('MobileApp',[ "ngRoute", "mobile-angular-ui", 
"mobile-angular-ui.gestures", "angucomplete-alt" , 'ui.tree'], function($rootScopeProvider) {   
    $rootScopeProvider.digestTtl(20); // 20 being the limit of iterations. 
  }
);
```